# Can we get an inbox message when a question we ask is marked as a duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, duplicates

I posted a question on askubuntu, unfortunately it was a duplicate of a previous question (I did search, sorry!). However, I came back a few times over the next few days to check the homepage to see whether I had any inbox messages informing me of any answers or comments on the question I had asked. As there were none I assumed it hadn't been answered.

Eventually I went to the page of the actual question to see that it had been marked as an exact duplicate, which is fine but would it not be helpful to have a message sent to the question-asker to inform them their question has been marked as a duplicate?

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: Or thinking about it, it may be easier for whoever marks the question as a duplicate to leave a comment saying they have done so. That should trigger an inbox message.

Comment: This happens automatically. I can't tell if you get notified though. I don't think that I have ever asked a question that was a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user with [cast close and reopen votes](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions) votes to close a question as a duplicate you do get a inbox notice.

A small comment is left in to the message automatically so the user is warned and can review or at least comment on the duplicate warning, sometimes they are incorrect or the OP can adjust the question to better describe why it is not a duplicate.

What happened in your case was that a moderator closed your question as a duplicate because it was [an obvious one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105158/where-can-i-see-a-list-of-updates-that-ive-previously-installed). No voting, no arguments, not comments required. Its not a matter of a possible duplicate, its a dupe.

There is no notice in such cases because there is no accusation, only a sentence, the question is closed.

I agree with what you recommend, leaving a comment when closing a question sounds to be a good solution, but truth be told you can also check your user page instead of the inbox for your questions status.